# Конструирование без инициализации

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Вопрос к гуру по стандартам C++ - что нынешний стандарт говорит о таком коде, вполне компилируемом и VC++, и [GCC](http://ideone.com/EimcRI):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    Test()             { cout << "Test()" << endl; }
    Test(int x):val_(x){ cout << "Test(" << x << ")" << endl; }
    Test(const Test& t):val_(t.val_) {
        cout << "Test(const Test& " << t.val_ << ")" << endl; }
    Test& operator = (const Test& t)  {
        cout << "Test& operator = (const Test& " << t.val_ <<")" << endl;
        val_ = t.val_;
        return *this;}
    ~Test()           { cout << "~Test()" << endl; }
    int val() const { return val_; }
private:
    int val_ = 0;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test t = t;
    cout << t.val() << endl;
}
```

Получается, что мы по сути создаем объект без инициализации полей, выполняя только копирование объекта в самого себя, т.е. мусора на свое же место?

Comment: Это UB, уже было на руСО, только поискать надо

Comment: @ixSci Да я догадываюсь :), но хотелось бы узнать, где именно (и как именно) указано, и почему явно не запретить? Дорого проверять?

Comment: UB потому что идёт использование неинциализированной переменной в `val_(t.val_)`. Почему не запретят — не знаю, наверное потому, что это corner case и нет смысла с ним морочить голову.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Такое объявление имеет неопределенное поведение.

Рассмотрите программу

```
struct A
{
    A() : n(0), p(nullptr) {}

    A(const A &a) : n(a.n), p(new int[n])
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) this->p[i] = a.p[i];
//      std::copy(a.p, a.p + n, this->p);
    }

    ~A() { delete[] p; }

    size_t n;
    int *p;
};

int main()
{
    A a = a;
}
```

Так ни значение `n` , ни значение `p` не были инициализированы, а при этом вызывается конструктор копирования, копирующий объект в сам себя, то будет иметь место попытка выделения динамически памяти для массива неопределенного размера и обращение по адресу, который имеет неопределенное значение.

В стандарте C++ написано (12.7 Construction and destruction)

> 1 For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any
>   non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor
>   begins execution results in undeﬁned behavior.

В стандарте C, который является нормативным документом также для стандарта C++ также упоминается, что (6.2.6 Representations of types)

> 5 Certain object representations need not represent a value of the
>   object type. If the stored value of an object has such a
>   representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does ot have
>   character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is
>   produced by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object
>   by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the
>   behavior is undefined.50) Such a representation is called a trap
>   representation.

В приведенном примере выше, члены класса используются до вызова конструктора, так как они не были инициализированы конструктором, когда идет обращение к ним в конструкторе копирования, чтобы их значения использовать для инициализации создаваемых членов класса нового объекта. Кроме того эти члены класса могут иметь так-называемые trap-представления.

Comment: Спасибо, я как-то не воспринял это как использование до инициализации :)

Comment: @Harry Не за что. Рад ответить.